# Should I use web service or web scraping for my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, web-services, web-scraping

I'm going to build an iPhone app and it's going to take some information from a website and I'm going to display it in a custom way. I have read in a few places that I should not use web scraping and use web services instead because it only needs to do it once and it will take off heavy lifting from server side.

What kind of information that I'm going to take from the website is names of soccer teams, date of the upcoming game and time. So do you have some pros and cons what I should go with?

Here is the website i would want to get the information from:

http://www.gp.se/sport/kommandematcher

How would I go to so I could parse that information? What would I start with?

Comment: You'll need to do something on a server of your own. Does the website you cite offer a web service or API? If so, you should use that - if not you would have to scrape it yourself from your server. You could have a look at Import.io for this - they allow you to create a scraping API without much programming.

Comment: Thank you for your answer halter.
It was a good suggestion and import.io works really good but it won't help me because the data that i want to get changes everyday after 00:00 and their service don't provide schedule re-crawls.

The website do not provide a web service or an API

Comment: Doesn't it? I thought import.io [specifically offers an API](https://import.io/docs/). (Note: halfer, not halter - use the @ symbol and tab completion `:)`).

Comment: Haha i think you misunderstood me. The website i am going to get the data from do not offer an API but import.io does ^^, I mailed them if it would be possible to get new information for my app every time the clock hits 00:00(new day).
I actually mailed them and asked if they could provide something like a scheduled re-crawl and they said they can't but they are thinking about doing it for a future update :(. @halfer (sorry bout the name before :P)

Comment: Since import.io offers an API, you can define a crawl using their toolset, and then call it up on a schedule on your own server. Sure, import.io don't offer their own scheduler, but as far as I can tell you can call their stuff using your own? I am surprised they did not suggest that to you.

Comment: Since i have never used a server before in this situation do you have a link i could start on?
Also would this server be able to handle many users cause my applikation will have many users in a month or so.

Thank you for you for always answering and taking your time to help me @halfer

Comment: Other than the link I added in my second comment, I don't have any other links, no (I could go searching, but unfortunately that's your job `;-)`). I expect it's really easy though - develop the crawler using their desktop software, then use the API to trigger it. The latter is probably 20 lines of code.

Comment: Hmm ok. Can you at least point me at the right direction? Since i have no experience and don't know what to search. All my searches ended up with SharedPoint which i don't think is the correct thing. Maybe you know a server provider that you can point me to?

Thanks @halfer

Comment: Get it working on your machine first, I would. You need to be able to type `php runMyScrape.php` at your console and it trigger the import.io scrape. You can worry about the schedule later (for which you will probably use `cron`). Please read the import.io documentation, it will contain examples.

Comment: Maybe you have misunderstood me. I'm not scraping to post it on a webpage. Im scraping to get the results on my iphone application. i don't see why i should need to run a .php for that.

I did got it to work on my iphone app. The data is shown on the log. All i need to do know is to make it appear on the Iphone Simulator instead of the log @halfer

Comment: No, I've not misunderstood the problem. In my opinion it is quite normal for a mobile device to request a scrape from your service, so that you have control of the process and can monitor the health of the scraper. That will allow you to change/improve the scraper easily. That said, it is simpler to do it direct from the device, sure. If you wish to do it that way, I've no idea - not done any iOS development.

Comment: Yea. Now that i read a little more about it i learned that its the best to have a server do the scraping and then so my clients can take the information from the server. Just like you said from the start :) @halfer

Comment: One thing it's worth bearing in mind is that scraping from a single server technically leaves you more vulnerable to IP blocking, if you are scraping a single service. Of course, don't do anything that would make a target want to block you!

Comment: Do anything like what example? @halfer

Comment: Excessive request rate or bandwidth usage, downloading material that is copyright, or fetching in contravention to a terms of service, etc. It's their server and they can block anyone for any reason they wish, in general. For example, I heard eBay apparently don't like price comparison scrapers.

Comment: Hmm okay yes got it.
Since the server that I'm going to use only needs to scrape once per day i think i should be ok. Also what I'm scraping is just information about upcoming games for a soccer division. But thanks anyway for the tips :D